# With git, how do you search for a file pattern with `git log` instead of a file path?

Tags: git, version-control

You can limit your `git log` search to a file like so:

```
git log [branch] -- foo.c
```

But how would you limit the search to a file pattern instead of a full path?

- Consider that you may run `git log`
  on another branch, where shell
  expansion of `*` won't work, so you
  can't depend on the shell to do the
  file pattern matching.
- Also, you can't specify a branch with
  `git ls-files`.

Comment: I'm starting to think that this feature doesn't exist as a simple command-line option...

Comment: maybe this was added to a later version of git, but this works for me: `git log -- "*/foo.c"` , including with the branch specification.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tend to do things like this:

```
git ls-files [--with-tree=<branch>] [path] | grep '<pattern>' | xargs git log [branch]
```

Comment: You can't specify a `branch` with `git ls-files` as of at least git 1.7.3, so you'd have to checkout every branch.

Comment: P.S. You could use `ls-tree -r --name-only` too.

Answer (score 14):

Or just drop the leading `.`, i.e.:`git log -- *foo.c`, or even `git log -- ./*foo.c`

Comment: If you want more complex regex matching, use perl and pipe the output into git log --

Comment: This is incorrect. It will only find commits that match the file pattern if the file exists on the file system. The * will be expanded by the shell if the file exists. So if you do `git log some_other_branch -- *foo.c` it wont find what you're looking for in all cases.

Comment: I don't understand the down-votes here (or the "this is incorrect" comments.) Just quote the pattern so the shell doesn't expect the wildcard (unless I'm misunderstanding the question.) And there's no need for (nor was there mention of) full regex for file pattern matching. Just simply use:  `git log --name-only -- "*/*foo*"` (or `git log {branch} ...` etc) and it will find all files matching the pattern.

Comment: Ah, if you quote the pattern then it's applied by Git when searching the files. I can't change the downvote until the question is edited, so if someone changes it I'll change my vote.

Comment: I'd recommend editing this answer to point out that you can quote the wildcard so git (and not the shell) will expand it - this was a huge game-changer for my use case.

Comment: This should be the top answer because its simple but effective.

Answer (score -4):

Use the `--glob` option.

Ref: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

Comment: Nope, that's for globbing on refs, e.g. `foo-*` to show logs for the branches `foo-a`, `foo-b`, and so on.